# Polyfill for css :target, not(), and [tilde] sibling selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, polyfills

I'd like to start using the css :target, not() and ~ sibling selectors now.  Is there a polyfill or some other solution for these?  I'd prefer to be able to simply use the css for them over using js/jQuery to simulate them for every use.

Comment: `~` is supported by most browsers including IE7+, so you *can* start using that now. As for the first two, well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE9.js polyfills everything you're looking for.

http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html

Comment: IE9.js might make page rendering very slow due to its repair all instead of selectively filling the desired missing required features.

Comment: For users of minified css files, it is annoying that css is incorrectly applied, especially in IE8, due to [bug #273](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=273) in IE9.js.

Answer (score 4):

This one also does the work: [http://selectivizr.com/](http://selectivizr.com)