# What's the simplest markup to display text upon clicking an image? No toggling, just simple CSS

Tags: css

What's the simplest markup to display text upon clicking an image?

No toggling, CSS or Javascript. I have a series of thumbs that I would like put a caption to when clicked. I've been searching for hours for what seems to be so simple and I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach is rather simple, but it makes the image caption text visible only until something else is clicked on in the page so that a link is followed. (It’s not quite clear from the question whether this is OK.)

Make the image caption text initially invisible, using CSS. Make the image a link to its caption, and use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:target) pseudo-class to turn the caption to visible when the link is clicked on. Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/pA3dU/).

```
<style>
a img { border: none; }
.caption { visibility: hidden; }
.caption:target { visibility: visible; }
</style>
<a href=#capt1><img src=test1.png alt=foo></a>
<div class=caption id=capt1>Image caption text</div>
<a href=#capt2><img src=test2.png alt=foo></a>
<div class=caption id=capt2>Image caption text 2</div>
```

As a side effect, the page may move down a bit, due to clicking on a link. If this is a problem, you could use “self-pointing” links instead:

```
<a href=#capt1 id=capt1><img src=test1.png alt=foo><br>
<span class=caption>Image caption text</span></a>
```

and then you would modify the selector in the essential CSS rule:

```
:target .caption { visibility: visible; }
```

This works across browsers except IE 8 and older. They can be covered using polyfill, i.e. JavaScript code that emulates support to the pseudo-element in browsers without native support. See [Polyfill for css :target, not(), and [tilde] sibling selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190456/polyfill-for-css-target-not-and-tilde-sibling-selectors)

Comment: Hi Jukka, this is actually very visually close to what I'm looking for, except, I need the image 2 caption to replace the Image 1 caption in the same spot where the Image 1 caption was. Is it possible for you to work this through? Thank you, Natalie

Comment: @Natalie, if I understand correctly, you would have the caption shown in one fixed place on the page. This is possible using absolute positioning, see http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/4VGE8/ (but beware that since abs. positioning takes an element out of the normal flow of layout, you need to reserve space for the element; in the jsfiddle I’ve just set a top margin for the `body` element since the caption text is naively placed at the very start of the page).

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
<label for="toggle">
    <img src="your image path" />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<span>your text here</span>
```

for the CSS

```
#toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

span{
    display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + span{
    display: block;
}

img{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But by doing this, against semantic rule of HTML.

[Here](http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/uvigt) the result.

Comment: Hi Bobby, can you try javascript intead then? also can you make it so it doesn't toggle?

Comment: "make it doesn't toggle", you mean the text appear after the mouse roll over the image?

Comment: Check my work [here](http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/ACqlH). this is the javascript version. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. so I have a bunch of thumbnails. When you click on one, I need a caption to appear. When you click on another thumbnail, I need a different caption to appear in its place (meaning the captions should replace one another in the same spot depending on which thumbnail they click). Hope this clarified what you needed to know. I really appreciate your help...

Comment: When I say that I dont wan't it to toggle, specifically I mean that when you click on it once, the caption should appear. when you click on it again, the caption should still be displayed (doesn't hide). However, I want the caption to change when a different thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: Ok I got it Natalie. check [this](http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/qGpCf) work. I hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Although your answer is great I actually found one that didn't use jquery or javascript but you're awesome help!

Comment: hi bobby.. I'm putting together your code ( http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/qGpCf ) and it doesn't seem to be working for me. Am I missing something? I put in the html, css and js exactly as I saw in your example...

Comment: have you included the latest jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery on() for each of the images, then use those click events to .toggleClass('visible') on the captions.

Comment: is it possible to use CSS only? I appreciate your response.

Comment: showing a text that is hidden, is always toggling no matter how you flip or turn it - either toggle something on the image or the caption - It's the only real answer as I see it, of course you could skip the jQuery and use pure javascript that goes without saying

Comment: In that case, could anyone try giving me a JS/HTML code for it?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get it to work with something like:

```
<img src="myimage.png" tabindex="1" /><div class="caption">Some text!</div>
```

CSS:

```
img~.caption{display:none}
img:active~.caption{display:block}
```

However, this is hacky at best. Something like this should really be done in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way? Yes! Is there a cross-browser way? No!

If you're not worried about it being cross browser or valid HTML, then this could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/XRBCF/

HTML:

```
<input hidden/>​
```

CSS:

```
input{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -o-apperance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -ms-appearance:none;
    padding:0;
    border:0;   
    background-image:url(http://placedog.com/400/300);
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    display:block;
    cursor:default;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

input:focus:after{
    content:"TEST";
    background-color:red;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:270px;
}
​
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the image in the jsfiddle. And why would anything happen?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: IE, Chrome, Firefox... On which browser did you see anything happen?

Comment: Safari. Like I said, it's possible with CSS3, not cross browser.