# Is there a way to group siblings into sections

Tags: css, markdown

The reason I ask, is that I am trying to have sections, that I can show and hide with CSS, in a plain Markdown rendered document. The rendered output might be some thing like this:

```
<h2>Hello</h2>

<p>content</p>
<p>more content</p>
<h2>Hello</h2>

<p>content not in a section</p>
<p>and neither is this</p>

<h2>World</h2>

<p>even more content</p>
<p>...whatever</p>

<h3>Title</h3>
<p>some stuff</p>

<h2>World</h2>

<p>...another paragraph</p>

<h2>Again</h2>
<p>more stuff</p>
<p>...and more</p>
<h2>Again</h2>
```

And I'd like to be be able to hide/show everything between, and including, the section 1 `<h2>` tags.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
h2 ~ p {
    ...
}
```

But this will obviously not stop at the next h2 tag. I realise this is probably not possible, but I thought I'd ask just in case I missed anything.

**Edit** Just to clarify, there could be many `h2` elements, and other `h?` elements as well e.g. `h3`

**Edit** I've managed to get something working with the following CSS

```
h2:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    color: blue;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2n) {
    color: red;
}

h2:nth-of-type(1) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: purple;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: black;
}

h2:nth-of-type(3) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: purple;
}
h2:nth-of-type(4) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: black;
}

h2:nth-of-type(5) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: purple;
}
h2:nth-of-type(6) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: black;
}

h2:nth-of-type(7) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: purple;
}
h2:nth-of-type(8) ~ *:not(h2) {
    color: black;
}

h3 {
    color: black;
}
```

It's gludgy, but then what I'm trying to do with the markdown HTML is fairly gludgy. The colours are standins for the show/hide stuff, just showing that I can target them. See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmWragg/ncmJu/)

Comment: In order to hide/show them you are going to need JS. In which case, why do you seek a CSS solution here?

Comment: The reason is that I am deriving the HTML from plain Markdown, and can only use CSS to style the HTML. I can use `display: none` in CSS to hide elements.

Comment: I don't follow. It doesn't matter where you are getting the HTML from. Do you want to *dynamically* introduce a visual change? You will need JS. Or do you want to introduce static changes? What's so special about the section1 header?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I want to statically show or hide sections. By using different CSS files the rendered document would then be able to hide/show different sections. So say, sales people would not be able to see the sections in the document that apply to devs for instance.

Comment: @wm.wragg That's poor design and prone to security problems.  If a user is not supposed to have access to specific information, they should not be served that information.  It should be hidden from the server side.  Otherwise, what's stopping them from viewing the source or disabling CSS?

Comment: Indeed it would be, but the hiding and showing of sections is purely to aid in the reading of the document. The sales people are welcome to check out the dev sections, and would be encouraged to do so, but if they are just interested in the sales stuff, then having a filter is very useful. The reason for all this, is that we are trying to find a nice simple way to do agile documentation. The reasoning being that the document travels with the idea from first inception to final release. The filtering is to allow different views of the same document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can encapsulate the entire generated HTML into a single element (for instance `body`, or even a `div`):

```
<body>

<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>content</p>
<p>more content</p>

<h2>World</h2>
<p>even more content</p>
<p>...whatever</p>

</body>
```

In your CSS, you can target the `h2` elements by using [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type):

```
h2:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: blue;
}
h2:nth-of-type(1) ~ p {
    color: purple;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2) ~ p {
    color: orange;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9a6V/).
Do realize though that this is a rather ugly solution, not sure if it works properly in all browsers that support `nth-of-type`, and it is source-order dependent.

Comment: I realise that I can format HTML to encapsulate elements into sections in this way, but I am deriving the HTML from a rendered plain Markdown document, which does not support grouping by sections like this, but thanks though.

Comment: @wm.wragg Look at my new answer.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't quite do what I want, as I want to be able to close sections, without starting another one. But still gets me thinking. I didn't realise that the sibling selector would stop when it found another type of element that it didn't match.

Comment: @wm.wragg: The sibling selector does not stop when it finds another type of element.

Comment: @wm.wragg Technically it isn't "stopping", but other styles are overriding the previous ones.

Comment: Yeah I see now, that's why it has to use the `nth-of-type` pseudo element.

Comment: I've flagged this as the answer as I am able to get something working using the `nth-of-type` pseudo class. It does mean that I have to code for a set number of sections in the CSS, but I can make this large.

Answer (score 3):

if you use selector as :not() , it might be a way

http://codepen.io/anon/full/mxasv

for older browser use polyfill/jQuery
to convince you, some links ?

[Polyfill for css :target, not(), and [tilde] sibling selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190456/polyfill-for-css-target-not-and-tilde-sibling-selectors)

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Quiet soon , you won't need polyfill/jQuery, CSS2.1 is 15 years old ?

Comment: Interesting, can't say I grok the `:not` bit. Is the `:not` section referring to the first `h2` block?

Comment: let's read the selector: h2:target  ~ p ~ h2 ~:not(h2) ~ p  {} Do if <p>  is  after  h2:target followed in the by a <p> wich is followed in the flow by one <h2> wich is not followed by <h2> but followed by <p>

Comment: actually we could just select from h2 and end up with p :  h2:target ~   h2 ~ :not(h2) ~ p {} to hide any <p> passed the 2nd h2 after the one targeted (remenber we hide them all, then show ones after h2:target and then filter again to hide if after 3rd h2) that's a typical use of the selector :not() , selector are if (dom=selector) {style !}

Comment: Got you. I don't think this would scale very well. I meant to say in the question, that there could be many `h2` elements, and other `h?` elements as well.

Comment: fork and edit the codepen yourself, play with it, there will be no hurts :) the sibbling ~ selector dosesn't need to go through every tags, just jump from h2 to h2 on same level (end up with what you want to show/hide) last selector could be *

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using the `:not` pseudo class, combining that with the `nth-of-type` pseudo class, gave me something I could use.